# CORS Preflight not sent to server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors, preflight

I have a Spring Boot app that uses Spring Security and Cors filter. Having a `CorsFilter` as below, I try to make a cross origin request

```js
Axios.get("http://10.0.120.11:30500/user", { withCredentials: true })
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

from a page hosted at **http://localhost:8080** . However, the browser gives 401. Strange thing is that the browser doesn't send any preflight (`OPTIONS`) request.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("*");

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(list);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(list);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080"));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                //.authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**","/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .clientRegistrationRepository(getClientRegistrationRepository())
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(getClientRegistrationRepository(),"/oauth2/authorize"))
                .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                .and()
                .tokenEndpoint()
                .accessTokenResponseClient(new CustomTokenResponseClient())
                .and()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(cookieAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Browser probably doesn't want to send a pre-flight request for a `GET` request.

> Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server data (in particular, HTTP methods other than GET, or POST with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with the HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request.

Reference: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#functional_overview)

Comment: I use the same scenario (GET request with cookie credentials) with a dotnet core server and it works as expected. Is there something I miss on my server configuration?

Comment: Unlikely since pre-flight is handled by the browser/client.

Comment: Indeed, the request in question is a [_simple_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) one (i.e. it's not preflighted). The 401 must stem from some authorization issue. It's not a CORS issue.

Comment: I overcame the preflight problem by adding a header to my axios request (cache-control). However get request still missing the cookie . Cookie is a httponly, samesite attribute is not specified (spring boot doesn't have that option yet) and not secure. Maybe cookie settings doesn't allow it to be sent over cross origin requests.

Comment: @serkanz What's the point of triggering a preflight for the sake of it? Preflight or not, your problem with the cookie not being attached lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes @jub0bs I figured out that my authentication cookie doesn't have a samesite attribute. In order to make a cross origin request with JavaScript , it has to be samesite=none . Now I'm able to make it work. Thanks for the comments.